# Connection bluez with Nonin 9560 via HDP

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, bluez

I am trying to work with Nonin Onyx II Model 9560 from my computer (Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. & bluez 4.98-2ubuntu7) via HDP.

When I run my application on computer, I see that the oximeter find my application, create a channel with it and starts the association procedure.
I see the oximeter sends a query to associating,
my application sends a response, confirming the associating,
but oximeter repeats the first query again and then drops the connection.

It looks like it does not hear my application or does not understand it.

Query to associating, received from the oximeter:

E2 00 00 32 80 00 00 00 00 01 00 2A 50 79 00 26
80 00 00 00 80 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80
00 00 00 08 00 1C 05 01 00 00 9B 0B 01 91 00 01
01 00 00 00 00 00

My application's response:

E3 00 00 2C 00 00 50 79 00 26 80 00 00 00 80 00
80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 08 00 1C
05 01 00 00 9B 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

I found several examples in Internet confirming that these meassages are correct.

But what could be a cause of the problem more?

Regards,
Andrey

Answer (score 0):

You should send another text to request for data. 
See:
The manager queries the agent for its MDS object attributes. IEEE Std 11073-10404-2008

Answer (score 0):

If the oximeter is sending the E2 message (AARQ - association request) again, it did not receive, or did not like the E3 message (AARE - association response).

Normally the manager requests the MDS object right after association but it does not have to in this case. It is a standard configuration, no scanner object to be set, and the oximeter will send measurement events as soon as association is up.

One thing I found is that your E3 message sends back the system id of the oximeter, while it should send the manager's system id. I doubt that oximeter actually checks manager ID to be different of its own, but it is wrong to repeat back the agent's ID anyway.

I think I spotted the error in your response:

E3 00 00 2C 00 00 50 79 00 26 80 00 00 00 80 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 **00 80 00 00** 00 08 00 1C 05 01 00 00 9B 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

The bold part should be 80 00 00 00 (sys-type-manager). The 00800000 value is sys-type-agent, so the oximeter thinks you are another sensor :)

The assoc_resp_msg in https://github.com/signove/hdpy/blob/master/src/hdp/dummy_ieee10404.py is an example of well-tested E3 response for the oximeter.